# Is it possible to add collect tracking code(Einstein Recommendation snippet) to Mobile app

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobile, einstein, einstein-recommendations, sfmc-einstein

In Einstein Email Recommendation, I could see that we can add the javascript snippet to website in order to track customer behaviour and send data to Einstein. After reading through the salesforce documentation I could nowhere find if it is possible to embed the code snippet to iOS / android as well for tracking. Please let me know if someone has implemented this on mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at the [API collect code](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/pb-collect-tracking.html)

> Einstein Recommendation Collect Tracking calls are available to be implemented with a server side option. To use these implementation methods, make an HTTP POST call to the appropriate URL, with the corresponding payload parameter values.

And also review this section of the SDK if you are using this

[Android](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/analytics/analytics.html)

> Einstein Recommendations analytics uses a unique identifier to attribute collected analytics to a specific user. By default, the SDK uses the contact key as this identifier, called the PIID. Your app can explicitly set this value. Review setPiIdentifier and setUseLegacyPiIdentifier for details and configuration information.
>
> If the PIID isn’t set or is null and the SDK is configured to use the Legacy PI identifier, the SDK sends the contact key as the PIID.

[iOS](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/analytics/personalization-collect.html)

> Einstein Recommendations analytics uses an unique identifier to attribute collected analytics to a specific user. By default, the SDK uses the contact key as this identifier, called the PIID. Your app can explicitly set this value.
>
> The Mobile Push SDK has an optional configuration option called useLegacyPiIdentifier. This option replaces an absent or empty PIID with the MobilePush contact key. If this configuration option is false, the SDK doesn’t replace an absent or empty PIID. Review Configure the SDK to configure the SDK with pianalytics and useLegacyPiIdentifier.